# Need to SUM the column values upto same rowno

Tags: sql, select, sum, subtotal, rowsum

I have a scenario, where I am going to show the sum of the column values upto specific row values. where i am giving category A,B and C from subtotal. if subtotal hvs 80, i will give A, and from 81-90 B and 91-100, is set as 100

for example

```
Class   totalstudent     subtotal        category 
1        20                20             A
2        30                50             A
3        15                65             A
4        20                85             B
5        10                95             C
6         5                100            C
```

how to show subtotal as in above scenario. need to write fetch query in SQL.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

```
USE CTE and get your desired result :


CREATE TABLE #Table(Class INT, totalstudent INT,category    
VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO #Table(Class , totalstudent ,category )
SELECT 1,20,'A' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,30,'A' UNION ALL
SELECT 3,15,'A' UNION ALL
SELECT 4,20,'B' UNION ALL
SELECT 5,10,'C' UNION ALL
SELECT 6,5,'C' 

;WITH CTE ( _Class , _totalstudent , _subtotal , _category) AS
(
   SELECT Class , totalstudent ,totalstudent ,category
   FROM #Table WHERE Class = 1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT Class , totalstudent , totalstudent + _subtotal  ,category
   FROM #Table
   JOIN CTE ON Class = _Class  + 1
)

SELECT * FROM CTE
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform running total operation

select * into #t
from ( select 1 Class ,20 totalstudent
        union all 
        select 2,30 
        union all
        select 3,15
        union all
        select 4,20
        union all
        select 5,10
        union all
        select 6,5 ) x

SELECT class,totalstudent,subtotal,
CASE WHEN subtotal<=80 THEN 'A' 
    WHEN subtotal between 81 and 90 THEN 'B' 
    WHEN subtotal between 91 and 100 THEN 'C' END Category
FROM ( SELECT t2.class, t2.totalstudent ,SUM(t1.totalstudent) subtotal
        FROM #t t1
        JOIN #t t2 on t1.class <=t2.class
        GROUP by t2.class, t2.totalstudent
        )x
    ORDER BY CLASS

Answer (score 0):

Check This.

```
        SELECT Class,totalstudent, 
        SUM(totalstudent)over(order by Class) as subtotal,
        Case When SUM(totalstudent)over(order by Class) <= 65 then 'A'  
        When SUM(totalstudent)over(order by Class) < 86 then 'B'  
        When SUM(totalstudent)over(order by Class) > 85 then 'C'  end As category  
        FROM #Table
        group by Class,totalstudent
        order by Class
```